# Handling data URIs for images in a dynamic site

Tags: php, css, http, uri

I'm looking to cut down on HTTP requests for a mobile site and, as part of this, would like to utilise data URIs for sending images inline. Each page may load up to 12 thumbnails at a time, which are likely to change on refresh.

Basically i have 2 options; running base64_encode on the images on a per-request basis, or storing the encoded data in a DB and fetching that. The latter would involve a bit more work as the thumbnails may be updated periodically, so ideally I'd like the first solution, but only if the performance of base64_encode is such that it can handle encoding 12 thumbnails per page.

I'd be appreciative of any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You should serve your image as plain image file, but from a separate domain. Because of how files are serve to the client, using a domain for images or medias could be more appropriate.

Also you should check caching server like Squid : http://www.squid-cache.org/

Just store in your database the file path.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi - on mobile in particular I'm not sure this is a great idea as certain platforms will restrict the number of concurrent connections (much more heavily than on the desktop).